# Horizontal Site Issues

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I am creating a horizontal scrolling site that will dynamically resize itself when i add the javascript to it later. However i started setting up the HTML and the code seems to cause a issue when i put another **div** inside of the div that makes up my dynamic code.

Also, would someone with more experience like to explain the drawbacks of using such a code if there are any?

```
#main_cont {
   height : 500px;
   white-space : nowrap;
   overflow-x: scroll;
   width: auto;
}
.ads {
   display : inline-block;
   height : 100%;
}
```

Is there a way for me to adjust the code below so that i can put divs and potentially images inside of it. I don't want to use a Javascript fix for this. thank you in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/YVyFA/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing `vertical-align: top;` for your panels

```
.wlds {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YVyFA/3/)**

Also you don't need javascript to resize your layout, use a fluid layout by setting height and width in percentage values

Comment: thank you. that actually fixed everything when i returned everything back to the percentage values. I greatly appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a link that might be able to explain how to make a website that requires horizontal scrolling. Try this tutorial by [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-a-horizontally-scrolling-site/). Hope this helped. Have a good day.

Comment: I did find this a while ago, but the information seemed to be a bit dated. So i did more searching to find what might be a better solution, and it seems that this might be it. No Javascript needed, pure CSS & HTML horizontal site here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the *quickest and dirtiest* solution to this is to give the `#main-cont` div a specific width and make the `.wlds` divs floated. So add the following CSS rules:

```
#main-cont {
    width: 783px;
}

.wlds {
    float: left;
}
```

[**JSFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/YVyFA/2/)